# How to create a while(true) in a AsyncTask whithout blocking the Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have created an `AsyncTask` and I have to create an `while(true)` on my `AsyncTask`.

How can I execute such an unbounded loop upon handling a button click in my Activity class without blocking?

Comment: `doInBackground()` is the thread method, so do it there. Though, `AsyncTask` really isn't intended to be used in this way so using a standard Java thread would probably be better or restructuring the logic so you don't use infinite loops.  Especially since you absolutely need a way to kill the thread if the user quits the app.

Comment: Please obmit the java android prefix. Everybody knows that android is commonly programmed in java and the relation to android is visible on your tags. And remember to accept helpful answers. You accepted none on your 5 questions.

Answer (score 4):

How others said a infinit loop without a break condition isn't a nice user experience. 
First get a instance for your AsyncTask:

```
 PostTask pt = new PostTask(this);
 pt.execute();
```

Try this in your `doInBackground()`:

```
while(!this.isCancelled()){
    // doyourjobhere


}
```

If the app is getting closed by the user the AsyncTask have to be stopped in your `onPause()`.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    pt.cancel(false);  
}
```

The[AsyncTask.cancel(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) sets `isCancelled()` to `true`, calls the `AsyncTask.onCanceled()` method instead of `onPostExecute()` and can be overwritten for your own purpose.

If you don't like this put your task in a Service.

Answer (score 1):

As said by the others, you should put your 'infinite loop' inside the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask.
However, this loop is not so infinite, because it must end when you exist the activity, or the application.
I suggest changing your `while (true) { }` to `while (! mustStop) { }` and set the boolean mustStop as an instance variable of your activity. So you'll be able to cleanly stop the process by setting `mustStop=true` (it would be a good idea to set this in the onPause method).

So this will be :

```
public class AsyncBigCalculActivity extends Activity {

private boolean mustStop = false;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mustStop=true; // Stop the infinite loop
}

....

@Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    mustStop=false;
    while (!mustStop) {
         ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the loop within the `doInBackground()` method of the AsyncTask. As a suggestion, you can add the AsyncTask as an inner class within your Activity.That way you can easily access the variables declared in your activity. Although the android documentation suggests to use AsyncTask only for short tasks. Its more advisable to create a runnable object and put your `while loop` within the `run()` method and execute it using `ExecutorService`, which allows you to run asynchronous code in android in a thread-safe manner.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html